# How to perform a diff between each pair of files of a directory (and it's sub-directories)?

Tags: svn, diff

I have two versions of a project in two folders. I'd like to make a diff of every pair of identical file in each directory.
I want what (Tortoise) SVN does between a working copy and a repository, but locally.

Is it possible to use SVN diff to do this between to local folders ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe you just do recursive ordinary `diff` on the two directories?

Comment: OMG, I didn't know there was such an option in the diff command line utility. I'll try it now.

Comment: @xanu: That's normal with UNIX. There's always an option that does the job:)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use SVN so much as you want to use a diff tool. If you're using a Mac, Kaleidoscope is *fantastic*, allowing you to drop the two directories onto the icon in the Dock and it'd do the rest and show you a great diff.

Looks like this list of diff software might help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool